# What could be the next step after inconsistent exploratory factor analysis on a translated scale?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, scales, psychometrics

We are in the process of translating FACTG scale from English to Arabic. The scale includes 4 subscales (PWB (7 questions), SWB (7 questions), EWB (6 questions), FWB (7 questions)) .
Factor analysis for the Spanish version is :

[image]

On our pilot data (n = 23), we do :

```
fit <- principal(extractfactg(newfactg,'[PESF]'), nfactors=4, rotate="promax")
print(fit$loadings, cutoff = .3)

Loadings:
    RC1    RC3    RC2    RC4   
GP1  0.394         0.539       
GP2  0.317         0.540       
GP3         0.624              
GP4  0.484                0.406
GP5         0.480  0.506  0.363
GP6  0.366        -0.445       
GP7         0.769 -0.368       
GS1                       0.439
GS2                0.574 -0.770
GS3  0.582 -0.382              
GS4               -0.723       
GS5  0.489        -0.515 -0.421
GS6               -0.639       
GS7 -0.309  0.659 -0.575       
GE1  0.318                0.735
GE2                       0.544
GE3        -0.338         0.341
GE4  0.723                     
GE5                       0.646
GE6  0.726                     
GF1         0.919              
GF2         0.862  0.323       
GF3         0.535              
GF4  0.936                     
GF5  0.477                     
GF6  0.772                     
GF7  0.773                     

                 RC1   RC3   RC2   RC4
SS loadings    5.121 4.116 3.404 2.964
Proportion Var 0.190 0.152 0.126 0.110
Cumulative Var 0.190 0.342 0.468 0.578
```

The question is : Based on factor analysis of pilot data on a translated scale, can we make decisions to modify the translation of specific questions, How ? or can we accept the above analysis given the small sample size (n = 23) and proceed to collect more data ?

Comment: N=23 is just ridiculous for FA. Even for a pilot study. And such an important issue how to translate/modify an item wording cannot be a subject of a "pilot" study at all. Translating/modiying original formulations is very responsible (and risky) undertaking. Get a good, representative sample of n> 3-5 times the number of items and not less than 300. Conduct a proper study to check if the original factors are reproduced. Then maybe modify something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, given your goals, you might want to look at confirmatory factor analysis.

Second, your factor analysis results look very different in the two versions.

Third, I'm not sure factor analysis is the way to search for translation problems.  It might help a little, but translation of items like this is hard. The same words mean different things culturally, especially with regard to psychological and social issues. I remember one study that translated a survey on menstrual pain into Chinese.  They checked the translation in many ways. Then they gave the same survey to women who were bilingual and found that they got different results.

Fourth, I would spend time with the names of the responses.  Since your results are so different in the two languages, it's probably not an issue of badly translating a single question.  But the responses are used in every question.

Finally, I would try to find a bunch of people who are fully fluent in both English and Arabic (although you say the FA is for Spanish ....) and have both individual discussions with the people and also group discussions.